# DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT error when using http-request module

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate, http-request

I use http-request nodejs module to send a get request by the following code scippet

```
http.get({
    url: 'https://xxx.yyy',
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    headers: {'Authorization':'xxxxxwdw'}
}, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    console.log(res.code, res.headers, res.buffer.toString());
});
```

it always show "DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT" error. I have already try setting process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0'; or adding "rejectUnauthorized: false" to the get option, it still have the same problem.

Any idea? Thanks you.

Comment: In the same place, any solution found? Thank you